# How do I encrypt user.settings

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, settings, user.config

I'm developing a windows desktop application with C# .NET4.0 VS2010 on Windows 8.1.  I've a range of settings that I store using the .NET settings mechanism.  These have user scope so, when set within the application they are written to Users\username\AppData\Local\companyname\App.exe_URL_randomstuff\versionno\user.config.

These settings include some user registration information that I need to keep hidden.  My research suggests that I should be able to encrypt settings using an RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider but all the examples I've found for this relate to encrypting app.config rather than user.config (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx).

My question therefore is can user.config be encrypted and if so how?  I note that when I instance a System.Configuration.Configuration object I can set the ConfigurationUserLevel to PerUserRoamingAndLocal.  When I examine the object via the debugger it seems to be refering to the correct user.config file but when I go on to instance a ConfigurationSection to protect it returns null.  The code looks like this:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                    ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.AppSettings;

connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
```

I'm thinking that config.AppSettings is probably not correct but I'm not sure what to replace it with.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: This article will give you two options: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

Comment: Ar you doing a `config.Save()` after that code?

Comment: @hatchet - Yes, belt-and-braces I'm using config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full).

Comment: @neoistheone It's a useful article (I'm refering to the encrypt everything option) but leaves me wondering what I should be naming my section if I use config.GetSection.  I tried config.GetSection("Progname.Properties.Settings") but this still returns null.

Comment: I would imagine that Microsoft should have that built in as an option!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it working now.  I was correct to be using ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal to access my user.config file.  The problem was with config.AppSettings.  I was on the right track replacing this with config.GetSection("Progname.Properties.Settings") but I got the naming wrong.  The working code now is as follows:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.GetSection("userSettings/Progname.Properties.Settings");

connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
```

"Progname" is whatever your assembly is called.  Thanks to @neoistheone and @hatchet for your input.

Comment: In my case the section name was "userSettings/Progname.MySettings".

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand, how this will encrypt user.settings.

Comment: Can you please provide me usage of this? how to use this to protect user.config?

Comment: @Fawad Read up about the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider class.  A good starting point with examples is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider(v=vs.110).aspx